# Centering elements in gris both vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have tried to make sure that whenever new elements are added to the grid, the row which has one div should be center to the middle of the grid but it's not working for me. Any help on this, it's a school project and we are allowed to use on html and css, no javascript??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkVLu.png)

I was expecting the 3rd div to be at the center of the grid since it's only on div at the row

my css

```
.places{
border: 1px red solid;
vertical-align: text-top;
}

.places h1{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.places article{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 20px;
    padding: 30px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.places article div{
    border: #FF5A5F 1px solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>7-index.html</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="view-port" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Wiseman Umanah">
        <meta name="description" content="A simple website with a header and footer(css)">
        <link rel="icon" href="images/icon.png" type="image/png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/4-common.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/3-header.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/3-footer.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/4-filters.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/5-filters.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/6-filters.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/7-places.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="airbnb-logo"></div>
        </header>
        <div class="container">
            <section class="filters">
                <div class="locations">
                    <h3>States</h3>
                    <h4>Nigeria, Kenya</h4>
                    <div class="popover">
                        <h2>Nigeria:</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Lagos</li>
                            <li>Akwa Ibom</li>
                        </ul>
                        <h2>Kenya:</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Nairobi</li>
                            <li>Eldoret</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="amenities">
                    <h3>Amenities</h3>
                    <h4>Hot Tubs, Hot Springs</h4>
                    <div class="popover">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Ostrich Pillow</li>
                            <li>Lamp</li>
                            <li>Tv</li>
                            <li>PlayStation 5</li>
                            <li>Dish Washer</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="button">Search</button>
            </section>
            <section class="places">
                <h1>Places</h1>
                <article>
                    <div>
                        <h2>My Home</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Tiny House</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2>A suite</h2>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>Best School</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```